# Windows execute winword from it's path

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

If I type winword (winword.exe and probably other variations work too) in the cmd anywhere on windows, it opens Word (default Office application). But if I am on the actual folder that contains WINWORD.EXE, it doesn't open. Why is that??

Comment: Check `where winword`. Maybe there are more such files?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Executables in the current folder have the priority in the order of execution, so there is some problem with the folder or with the name you are typing.

Comment: Thanks JosefZ there were 2 files with the same name and the "real" winword.exe was the other one. By the way, the "real" .exe is 0 KB !!! Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because windows uses the "PATH" Variable to locate any executable file (Those ending with one of these extensions: .COM .EXE .BAT .CMD .VBS .VBE .JS .JSE .WSF .WSH and .MSC by default).

Which File extensions should be matched are stored in the variable "PathEXT", it can be advantageous to add other extensions here for command line executables to find them.

**You can see the contents of the path variable by three methods:**

Method A)  Typing "Path" at the CLI returns the contents of the Path variable.

```
Y:\>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common.....
```

Method B)  Typing "echo %Path%" at the CLI returns the contents of the Path variable.

```
Y:\>echo.%path%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common.....
```

Method B)  Typing "Set Path" at the CLI returns the contents of the Path variable.

```
Y:\>set path
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common.....
```

**You can change the contents of the Path variable in two ways:**

Method 1)  This method is Temporary

```
SET "Path=%Path%;[NEW PATH]"
```

Method 2)  This method is permanent.

```
PATH %Path%;[NEW PATH]
```

Showing and Setting the PathExt Variable for the current CMD instance:

Y:>set PathExt
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Y:>set "PathExt=%PathExt%;.groovy"

Y:>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.groovy

Comment: Just realised you weren't asking how the ath works, yeesh, what a waste.